# Spring Data JPA query generation by field

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data

I had a method in a ProjectRepository that looked something like this:

```
findByUserID(int userID);
```

This would list all projects that reference a certain user. Because of other requirements, I now need to reference the User from the Project, instead of just the userID, like so:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userID", referencedColumnName = "userID")
private User user;
```

Which used to just be:

```
int userID;
```

So I replaced the method with:

```
findByUser(User user);
```

But this requires an extra call to the database to get the User object for a given userID. Is there a way to use the first method with my new class? If I just keep the first method, I get a

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property ID found for type User! Traversed path: Project.user.
```

Is this possible without writing a custom query?

Comment: What is the name of the ID property of User?

Comment: All my ID's use the convention: classNameID; e.g. userID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the User class contains is defined as:

```
public class User {
    private int userId;

    public User(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    //getters setters ommitted
}
```

and the Project class has a User object in it like so:

```
public class Project {
    private User user;

    public Project() {
    }
    //rest ommitted
}
```

It should according to the documentation be able to write a custom query in the repository that access the nested properties like project.user.userId by writing

```
findByUserUserId(int userId);
```

Or at least that's what I understood from reading the docs [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.details)

Comment: Yes, a custom query is probably the way to go. But I'm looking for a solution without having to write queries. I'm using Spring's query creation (and Hibernate) for all other database operations, so I'm interested in learning more complex method names. I can't find any in the documentation...

Comment: isn't the above solution using query creation? I do all my spring boot stuff that way. It's way faster and pretty cool. findByLastNameEqualsIgnoreCase(String lastName) like that sort of style right? Is that what you mean by query creation? Cos that's what findByUserUserId(int userId) is doing. It should in theory automatically generate a query select * from project where project.user.userId = :userId

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread your answer! I will try your solution right away. EDIT: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn annotation.

Comment: Where do I put that? If I put it in my User class and update my repository, I still get a PropertyReferenceException: No property ID found for type User